# Use of unsafePerformIO appropriate?

Tags: haskell, monads

Is using [`unsafePerformIO`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/System-IO-Unsafe.html) to allow read-only IO calls to non-changing files in pure code appropriate or is it going to cause a lot of problems?

The main reason is because I'd like to store them in containers and for example, make them an instance of `Ord`, but I can't seem to imagine how to do that without wrapping IO calls in `unsafePerformIO`.

Comment: I don't know if it would be problematic, but there might be a cleaner way to get what you're after. Read the files once into the data structure of your choosing, then pass them around as needed.

Comment: This sounds very unlikely to be a wise idea.  Perhaps you could ask more about exactly what you're trying to achieve, maybe in a separate question.

Comment: To elaborate on @TomEllis' remark, even if you are absolutely certain that the files are unchanging and available, you can't be certain about things outside of your Haskell program. Something else could delete the files, they could move, they could be renamed. All of those things could result in any consumer of your code suddenly blowing up. Using IO at least makes sure you know *where* your code could blow up. Now you've defined the surface area of code that can blow up to be "Anywhere in my program." Will you wrap your use of `==` and `>=` in `try` `catch` blocks?

Answer (score 2):

## On safety

Using `unsafePerformIO` in the way you describe should not cause any problems.

The thumb rule is: if you are using `unsafePerformIO` to define a function which could be defined without it in Haskell, then you are using it safely.

In your case, you essentially use it to achieve the same effect of defining some fixed values in your code. That is, you could just include your read-only non-changing files in your source code, at the cost of keeping the whole lot of data in memory. So your use is safe.

For example, if you invented a primality test which somehow exploits a fixed 100MB data table, then it would be alright to use `unsafePerformIO` to access an immutable file containing it. This would trade code purity for performance (memory footprint), without compromising safety.

## On appropriateness

Since `unsafePerformIO` is indeed unsafe (the burden of proving the program safe is on you), it should be regarded as a last resort, and definitely not as the default way for reading a file's contents.

It's hard to understand whether your case really justifies using `unsafePerformIO`. You should describe what you are trying to achieve in more detail.

I'd guess that, if your program is going to read the files and store their whole contents in memory, then you would get no performance advantage from `unsafePerformIO`, and you should use pure code instead.