# Is there something better than unsafePerformIO for this....?

Tags: haskell

I've so far avoided ever needing `unsafePerformIO`, but this might have to change today....  I would like to see if the community agrees, or if someone has a better solution.

I have a library which needs to use some config data stored in a bunch of files.  This data is guaranteed static (during the run), but needs to be in files that can (on very rare occasions) be edited by an end user who can not compile Haskell programs.  (The details are uninportant, but think of "/etc/mime.types" as a pretty good approximation.  It is a large almost static data file used throughout many programs).

If this weren't a library I would just use the IO monad....  But because it is a library which is called throughout my code, it literally forces a bubbling up of the IO monad through pretty much *everything* I have written in multiple modules!  Although I need to do a one time read of the data files, this low level call *is* effetively pure, so this is a pretty unacceptable outcome.

FYI, I plan to also wrap the call in unsafeInterleaveIO, so that only files that are needed will be loaded.  My code will look something like this....

```
dataDir="<path to files>"

datafiles::[FilePath]
datafiles = 
  unsafePerformIO $
  unsafeInterleaveIO $
  map (dataDir </>) 
  <$> filter (not . ("." `isPrefixOf`))
  <$> getDirectoryContents dataDir

fileData::[String]
fileData = unsafePerformIO $ unsafeInterleaveIO $ sequence $ readFile <$> datafiles
```

Given that the data read is referentially transparent, I am pretty sure that unsafePerformIO is safe (this has been discussed in many place, such as "[Use of unsafePerformIO appropriate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21647280/use-of-unsafeperformio-appropriate)").  Still, though, if there is a better way, I would love to hear about it.

---

UPDATE-

In response to Anupam's comment....

There are two reasons why I can't break up the lib into IO and non IO parts.

First, the amount of data is large, and I don't want to read it all into memory at once.  Remember that IO is always read strictly....  This is the reason that I need to put in the `unsafeInterleaveIO` call, to make it lazy.  IMHO, once you use `unsafeInterleaveIO`, you might as well use `unsafePerformIO`, as the risk is already there.

Second, breaking out the IO specific parts just substitutes the bubbling up of the IO monad with the bubbling up of the IO read code, as well as the passing around of the data (I might actually choose to pass around the data using the state monad anyway, so it really isn't an improvement to substitute the IO monad for the state monad everywhere).  This wouldn't be so bad if the low level function itself wasn't effectively pure (ie- think of my /etc/mime.types example above, and imagine a Haskell `extensionToMimeType` function, which is basically pure, but needs to get the database data from the file....  Suddenly everything from low to high in the stack needs to call or pass through a `readMimeData::IO String`.  Why should each `main` even need to care about the library choice of a submodule many levels deep?).

Comment: It would be better to separate the pure and IO parts of the API and add in one call for reading the file and getting a data structure and another call for using the data structure to do something. So something like - `getDataFiles :: IO [FilePath]` & `readDataFiles :: [FilePath] -> [String]`

Comment: You seem to be very well aware of the dangers of `unsafePerformIO` and you have an argument for why this is a safe use of it.  So I'd say it's up to you to decide if you want to use it.  It's never nice to use `unsafePerformIO`, but it is sometimes expedient.

Comment: @AnupamJain- I've updated my question with some comments

Comment: "Remember that IO is always read strictly"  This isn't true or we have a communications failure.  Which is it?

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson- I am not sure what you mean?  Take the `sequence $ readFile <$> dataFiles` above.  It doesn't read the files into memory lazily, instead it reads everything into memory.  In my case, there will be many files, I need to just read a few per run....  In the case of an error, I think readFile uses `error` (I'm not sure....), so the whole program just crashes....  Perhaps technically you can call that "not strict" :), but I think the point I am trying to make is clear.

Comment: `sequence $ readfile <$> dataFiles` *does* read the files lazily. It *opens* them all immediately, though.

Comment: @jamshidh - I have a few different ideas, but I do not know what to present. You have given us your proposed solution, but I am not clear on your exact problem.  Can you sketch out in rough code what you are doing?  Something like: A calls B calls C calls D and E. D and E need to use the config data in two separate external files.

Comment: @Davorak- I didn't mention the exact details of my full problem because it has a bunch of indidental details that would just cloud the question.  For this question, just take the  `extensionToMimeType` function I mentioned above as the concrete example.  This function is in a module, which is used by many other modules.  Because this function needs to read data from a datafile, everyone who uses it needs to run in the IO monad.  (actually, there are many data files instead of one, so perhaps I should reference "/usr/share/terminfo" instead of "/etc/mime.types")

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen- You might be correct....  I only verified that all the files were opened before I posted, not that they were read.  Nevertheless, having possibly hundreds of open file handles when you only need one is also a bad thing, which I need to avoid. :)

Comment: @augustss It may be expedient, but it deprives the new programmer of a useful learning experience, specifically how to use functors/applicatives/monads.

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez- As per my original comment, I've done the proper safe thing in many an other piece of code....  This isn't a learning experience.  Rather I am looking to see if this isn't in fact a rare case where unsafe makes sense.  With due respect to the help people have offered, as I mentioned in my update, no one has yet given me a suggestion that keeps the resource footprint down and/or doesn't unnecessarily explode the size of my code, so currently I'm preferring unsafe.  (BTW ....funny, I just spent the last hour watching your interview at the Haskell Cast:) ).

Comment: @jamshidh - If you access the majority of filedata to parse the data you need does the garbage collector collect that which you do not use again? If it does not then the main effect of this technique would be to lower the memory foot print while it was reading in configuration data, but the max foot print would be the same if you read it all at once or if you read it in as you do now with unsafeInterleaveIO.

Comment: for better resource usage you can use `mapM (unsafeInterleaveIO . readFile)` instead of `sequence $ readFile <$>`

Answer (score 5):

I agree with Anupam Jain, you would be better off reading these data files at a somewhat higher level, in IO, and then passing the data in them through the rest of your program purely.

You could, for example, put the functions that need the results of `fileData` into `Reader [String]`, so that they can just ask for the results as needed (or some `Reader Config`, where `Config` holds these strings and whatever else you need).

A sketch of what I'm suggesting follows:

```
type AppResult = String

fileData :: IO [String]
fileData = undefined -- read the files

myApp :: String -> Reader [String] AppResult
myApp s = do
  files <- ask
  return undefined -- do whatever with s and config

main = do
  config <- fileData
  return $ runReader (myApp "test") config
```

Comment: I just updated my question....  I didn't see your answer until after I added, but my comments apply here also.

Answer (score 1):

I gather that you don't want to read all the data at once, because that would be costly. And maybe you don't really know up-front what files you will need to load, so loading all of them at the start would be wasteful.

Here's an attempt at a solution. It requires you to work inside a free monad and relegate the side-effecting operations to an interpreter. Some preliminary imports:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Main where

import qualified Data.ByteString as B
import Data.Monoid
import Data.List
import Data.Functor.Compose
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Free
import System.IO
```

We define a functor for the free monad. It will offer a value `p` do the interpreter and continue the computation after receiving a value `b`:

```
type LazyLoad p b = Compose ((,) p) ((->) b)
```

A convenience function to request the loading of a file:

```
lazyLoad :: FilePath -> Free (LazyLoad FilePath B.ByteString) B.ByteString  
lazyLoad path = liftF $ Compose (path,id)
```

A dummy interpreter function that reads "file contents" from `stdin`:

```
interpret :: Free (LazyLoad FilePath B.ByteString) a -> IO a 
interpret = iterM $ \(Compose (path,next)) -> do
    putStrLn $ "Enter the contents for file " <> path <> ":"
    B.hGetLine stdin >>= next
```

Some silly example functions:

```
someComp :: B.ByteString -> B.ByteString
someComp b = "[" <> b <> "]"

takesAwhile :: Int
takesAwhile = foldl' (+) 0 $ take 400000000 $ intersperse (negate 1) $ repeat 1
```

An example program:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    r <- interpret $ do 
        r1 <- someComp <$> lazyLoad "file1"
        r2 <- return takesAwhile 
        if (r2 == 1)
            then return r1
            else someComp <$> lazyLoad "file2"
    putStrLn . show $ r
```

When executed, this program will request a line, spend some time computing `takesAwhile` and only then request another line.

If want to allow different kinds of "requests", this solution could be extended with something like [Data types à la carte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21395407/combining-free-types) so that each function only needs to know about about the precise effects it requires.

If you are content with allowing only one type of request, you could also use `Client`s and `Server`s from [Pipes.Core](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.1.0/docs/Pipes-Core.html) instead of the free monad.